# Validar que una fecha ingresada no sea mayor a 10 días después de la fecha actual

Tags: javascript, validación, date

Estoy realizando una validación de fechas en JavaScript, para ver que la fecha ingresada no sea mayor a 10 días desde la fecha actual. Y si es mayor, que me muestre un error.

Éste es mi código:

```js
var hoy = new Date();
var dias = parseInt(TxtFecha.value);
var calculado = new Date();
var diassumar = calculado.setDate(
  hoy.getDate() + 10
);
if (TxtFecha.value > diassumar) {
  MostrarMensaje("Error...", "Aviso del Sistema");
  //alert("Debe seleccionar el tipo de gestion...");
  return;
}
```

Comment: "Si es mayor que 10 días" ... ok, pero ¿mayor que 10 días que qué? ¿Si una fecha es posterior a 10 días desde la fecha actual? Y si es asi, ¿en dónde está el valor de esa fecha? ¿De dónde se obtiene?

Comment: @Mariano  si osea que primero debe coger la fecha actual ejemplo estamos 11/05/2017 que le sume 10 dias que quiere decir sea = 22/05/2017    es decir solo los dias .
ya que yo tengo un calendario que si yo en el calendario pongo 30 y ya es mayor a 10 dias me mande un sms de error o la validacion

Comment: **1** me imagino que debería ser 21/5/2017 (no 22) ... **2** ¿qué fecha debería ser inválida si es mayor a 10 días? Supongo que `TxtFecha.value`, pero eso es un input type=text?? en qué formato está la fecha que se ingresa??

Comment: @Mariano es string ahorita voy modificar con este codigo que tambien he intentado

Comment: @Mariano 1 : que si debe ser 21/05/2017  2 si es mayor a 10 debe ser invalida y el validacion   , si es un input type="text

Comment: @Mariano ? ???????????????

Comment: En [es.so] no se busca la ayuda de 1 persona, sino de la comunidad. Luego de publicar una pregunta, no deberías estar llamando a 1 usuario, sino esperando que alguien te responda, cualquier usuario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los pasos están comentados en el código:

```js
$(function() { //document ready
  const cantDias = 10;

  $("#validar").on("click", function() {
    //Obtener la fecha ingresada en el input
    // llevado a array dividido por "/"
    const textoIngresado = $("#TxtFecha").val().split("/");
    //Llevar a tipo Date
    //  mes -1 porque empieza en 0
    //  y llevar a hora 00:00:00
    var fechaIngresada = new Date(textoIngresado[2], textoIngresado[1] - 1, textoIngresado[0], 0, 0, 0, 0); 

    //Obtener fecha límite
    var fechaLimite = new Date(); //fecha actual
    fechaLimite.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0); //llevar a hora 00:00:00
    fechaLimite.setDate(fechaLimite.getDate() + cantDias); //sumarle 10 días

    //Validar
    if (fechaIngresada >= fechaLimite) {
      alert("Fecha incorrecta");
    } else {
      alert("Fecha válida");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML -->
<input type="text" id="TxtFecha" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy">
<input type="button" id="validar" value="Validar">
```

Comment: una consulta me salta un error en  const  , let porque

Comment: @Pierro porque estás con algún navegador que no soporta JavaScript moderno... Modifico el código para que lo puedas correr

Comment: es chrome la version 58.0.3029.96

Comment: @Pierro funciona bien en Chrome

Answer (score 1):

para tomar el valor de tu input y convertirlo a dateTime necesitas usar

```
var dias = new Date(TxtFecha.value);
```

ten en cuenta que te pondrá el valor de media noche del día en cuestión

```js
function contardias(){
    var hoy = new Date();
    var dias = new Date(TxtFecha.value);
     var calculado = new Date();
     var diassumar = calculado.setDate(
       hoy.getDate() + 10
      );
     if (dias > diassumar)
     {
         errormsg.innerHTML="Error...";


     }
 }
```

```html
<input type="date" name="bday" id="TxtFecha">
<button id="val" onClick="contardias()"> validar </button>
<p id="errormsg"><p>
```